# Is it possible to extend or override Wagtail views?

Tags: django, django-views, wagtail

I'm interested in adding some functionality to my wagtail blog to automatically post to social media when a post is published. Normally, the place to do this would be in the view.

I did find an app on github called `wagtail_share_social` but it has not been updated in 2 years, and I would rather not be reliant on a third party solution.

The Wagtail documentation has notes on extending views, but they seem to be limited to extending admin views, or views used in the dashboard rather than for serving up pages to non-logged in users.

Is it possible to extend or override the Wagtail views for serving non admin pages? If not, what would be the correct approach to add functionality when a page is served via Wagtail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to do this is probably to use the "after_page_published" hook and put your social media publishing code there https://docs.wagtail.org/en/latest/reference/hooks.html#after-publish-page

Comment: Ah thank you! I hadn't realized what 'hooks' was but it seems to be exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Do you know if the `after_publish_page` hook distinguishes between 'published' and 'finally published'? I know it's possible for a page to be considered 'published' without showing up to the public, for example.

Comment: Are you trying to distinguish between publishing and scheduled publishing? I am not sure but I think this hook would run when you set the go_live date and then again when the cron job makes the page live. In which case, you would want to check the page object to see if it is live or not before sending your social media notices. Try setting up a hook that just prints to your logs and then experiment.

Comment: After publish will run every time you publish, including updates. You need after_create_page which runs on first publish only. https://docs.wagtail.org/en/stable/reference/hooks.html#after-create-page